# How can I position text halfway between centered and left-aligned?

Tags: html, css

I need to have some text that is center aligned but pushed to the left so that it is in between center and left aligned.

```html
<th style="text-align:Center"> TextHere</th>
```

Comment: You should describe the things you want to achieve a little bit more. It's hard for us to figure out what your goal is.

Comment: so you need to have your th 50% wide than its parent. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an inner element that's half the width of the heading cell and centered. That element's contents will be left-aligned.

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
    text-align: center;
    background: pink;
}

th span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><span>Text Here</span></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You asked for inline CSS. I'll leave it to you to migrate to such. An embedded style tag might be better, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of `span` to `50%`, pull it to left and centralize the text

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

th{
    text-align: center;
    background: green;
    width:50%
}

th span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><span>Text Here</span></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Although, please remember, `inline-block` for `span` tag is ignored due to the float. If `float` has a value other than `none`, the box is floated and `display` is treated as `block`.